# Prove the lines of the orthocenter are concurrent BY Ceva's theorem

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that the lines of the orthocenter are concurrent by Ceva's Theorem (or its converse).

Edit: Ceva's theorem is the theorem stating in a triangle $ABC$, if the lines $AX$, $BY$, and $CZ$ ($X$ being on $BC$, and so forth) are concurrent, then:

$(BX/XC) * (CY/YA) * (AZ/ZB) = 1.$

The converse would be that given ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- the altitude of $A$ intersect line $BC$ at $D$ (i.e. $AD \perp BC$)
- the altitude of $B$ intersect line $CA$ at $E$ (i.e. $BE \perp CA$)
- the altitude of $C$ intersect line $AB$ at $F$ (i.e. $CF \perp AB$)
- $a,b$ and $c$ be the lengths of segments $BC,CA$ and $AB$ respectively

### $\triangle ABC$ has no obtuse angle

[image: acute triagnle ABC]
<sub>(source: [mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/o/o_assets/orthocenter_acute.jpg))</sub>

$$\frac{AF}{FB} \frac{BD}{DC} \frac{CE}{EA} = \frac{b \cos A}{a \cos B} \frac{c \cos B}{b \cos C} \frac{a \cos C}{c \cos A} = 1
$$

By Ceva's Theorem, the orthocenter exists.

### $\triangle ABC$ has an obtuse angle

Suppose $\angle B > 90^\circ$.  From the diagram below, it can be seen that altitudes $AD$ and $CF$ lie outside $\triangle ABC$.

[image: obtuse triagnle ABC]
<sub>(source: [mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/o/o_assets/orthocenter_obtuse.jpg))</sub>

\begin{align}
\frac{AF}{FB} \frac{BD}{DC} \frac{CE}{EA} =& -\frac{b \cos A}{a \cos (180^\circ - B)} \cdot -\frac{c \cos (180^\circ - B)}{b \cos C} \cdot \frac{a \cos C}{c \cos A} \\
=& \frac{b \cos A}{a \cos B} \frac{c \cos B}{b \cos C} \frac{a \cos C}{c \cos A} = 1
\end{align}

By Ceva's Theorem, the orthocenter also exists.